# Proving a function has bounded derivatives

Tags: real-analysis

The function in question is:

$ \mathrm{e}^\frac{1}{\left(4x+3\right)^2-1}  $   where $ x∈ (-1, -1/2) $

I've tried graphing the derivatives and it seems that they explode as $ x \rightarrow -1/2 $

Answer (score 0):

The function actually goes to $ 0$ when $x$ approaches the boundary of the interval, because the exponent shoots down to $-\infty$. This also happens for every derivative, and in particular they are all bounded in that interval.

Comment: how can I prove it ?

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x) =\mathrm{e}^\frac{1}{\left(4x+3\right)^2-1}$, then
$$f^{\prime} (x) =\frac{-8(4x+3)} {[(4x+3)^2-1]^2} \mathrm{e}^\frac{1}{\left(4x+3\right)^2-1}$$ which is zero in $x=-3/4$ so that it is its maximum (since $\lim_{x\to - 1^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to - (1/2)^-}f(x)=0$).

So $f(x) \le f(-3/4)$

Now if you take the derivative of $f^{\prime} $, which is $f^{\prime \prime} $, you should get the max point, so you can obtain: $f^{\prime} (x) \le f^{\prime} (x_{max}) $.

You should then be able to go on.

Comment: how do you know that the nth derivative will have a maximum?

Comment: I am really hopeful, because you have an exponential shooting to 0 and a polinomiale fraction in from of it, so my guess is that is will always be bounded thanks to the exponential

Comment: I just wanted to help with ideas

Comment: If you start seeing it works for a few derivatives then you can maybe prove every derivative will be a fraction of polinomiale multiplied by the exponential and then you could prove that if that's the case, then it is bounded

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$f'(x)=\frac{-8(4x+3)}{\left((4x+3)^2-1\right)^2}e^{\frac{1}{(4x+3)^2-1}} $$
and continuing the differentiation, we can see the $n$-th derivative is
$$f^{(n)}(x)=\frac{P_n(x)}{\left((4x+3)^2-1\right)^m}e^{\frac{1}{(4x+3)^2-1}} $$
where $P_n$ is some polynomial and $m$ is a positive integer. So, the $n$-th derivative is continuous in $(-1,-1/2)$ and to show it's bounded, it suffices to show the limits
$$\lim_{x\to (-1)^{+}}f^{(n)}(x),\lim_{x\to (-1/2)^{-}}f^{(n)}(x) $$
exist. Substitute $t=-\frac{1}{(4x+3)^2-1}\to\infty$ as $x\to (-1)^{+}$:
$$\lim_{x\to (-1)^{+}}
\frac{e^{\frac{1}{(4x+3)^2-1}}}{\left((4x+3)^2-1\right)^m}=\lim_{t\to\infty}(-t)^me^{-t}=(-1)^m\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{t^m}{e^t}=0$$
So the first limt is $P_n(-1)\cdot 0=0$. The second limit is handled in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to study $\exp(1/(x-1))$ on the set $(-1,0)$, or equivalently $f(x)=\exp(\frac{-1}x)$ on the set $(0,1)$. The result for your function then follows by repeated application of chain rule. This function  $f$ actually extends to a bounded and smooth function on $\mathbb R$, but it will be enough for your exercise to prove that
$$ f^{(n)}(x) = \frac{p_n(x)}{x^{2n}} f(x)$$
where $p_1$ is some polynomial of degree $n-1$,
which is proved inductively in many places, for instance [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function) Wikipedia page. This and the fact that $0\le f(x) \le C_n x^{2n}$ for every $n$ gives the boundedness near 0; the function is smooth away from zero so in particular bounded near 1.